# Ajax posting issue in asp.net mvc4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My Ajax posting is not working in asp.net mvc4.Ajax call not hitting the action.How to solve it?

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:8871/Account/Add",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',            
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: '2' }),
        success: function (data) { }

        });
```

my controller action is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: whats not working, whats the error, Is ajax call hitting action?

Comment: ajax call not hitting the action

Comment: have u seen in console what are the errors?

Comment: not any errors showing in console

Comment: why arent u using '@Url.Action("Add","Account")' for url

Comment: Make sure you added the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" file to the page
   edit: and I strongly advice you to follow @NitinVarpe reply as well!

Comment: also you don't need to stringify a single string.

Answer (score 0):

Change your url like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Add","Account")' ,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',            
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: '2' }),
    success: function (data) { }

    });
```